# selenium in visual studio

Tags: c#, selenium

Novice Selenium user here. I have experience with other ui automation tools, so I thought piece of cake. I got this. I am writing my code in C# using Visual Studio. I have this

this.txtLogin = this.driver.FindElement(By.Id("Username"));

When I use the Developer Tools in IE, I can see it. I even pasted the id do as to not risk a typo. As I was dorking around, I decided to screw around to see what I could see, maybe find a parent to help Selenium out. So I did

```
        this.parent = this.driver.FindElement(By.Id("divRight"));
```

which is a unique Div upstream of my text box. This is not being found either.

Can someone help me understand what I am missing? Thanks.

S

Answer (score 0):

I figured it! I had to switch frames. Thanks readers.